# Как на golang передать видео с веб камеры и звук с микрофона с одной программы на другую и потом в браузере это отобразить?

Tags: golang, видео, потоки-данных, streaming

Как на golang передать видео с веб камеры и звук с микрофона с одной программы на другую и потом в браузере это отобразить?
То-есть хочу,что б у клиента снимала данные- пересылала на сервер, а админ мог в веб интерфейсе это смотреть.
Подскажите хотя бы промежуточные шаги - с чего начать?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Неясно, зачем нужен сусликовый велосипед, когда существуют ffmpeg + [nginx-rtmp](https://habrahabr.ru/post/162237/) + flowplayer - на них разворачивается превосходный и горизонтально масштабируемый стек транскодирования видео в различные форматы

- разное разрешение,
- разное соотношение сторон,
- разный битрейт,
- разные целевые платформы и
- разные каналы доставки.

А еще, можно влупить туда HTTPS с привязкой клиентских сертификатов - и получить надежную систему защищенной от прослушки доставки контента.

Comment: Велосипеды - наше всё.

Comment: @"gbg" А Вы примеры не можете привести,если не сложно?я погуглил, но так как в этой теме ещё не очень разбираюсь- всёравно не знаю- с чего всётаки начать

Comment: @RakzinRoman я добавил в ответ ссылку на публикацию самого автора nginx-rtmp